# Force connetion through SSL Tunnel

Tags: tls, tunneling

All machines are Linux-based.

I want to force ssh (or telnet) to the 192.168.100.20 server from the laptop through the SSL Tunnel. What command should I use?

[image]

Comment: You might want to consider using `iptables` or `ufw` on 76.98.40.254 to block all incoming connections from 30.45.123.10 except those with destination port 443.

Comment: Depends on how your SSH tunnel is set up. A custom route could do the job possibly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous.

If you question is about not wanting anything to reach the destination server unless it reaches port 443, and for that `iptables` is the answer.

If your question is about connecting to SSH by passing inside a TLS tunnel first, it's not that simple. You cannot just throw SSH on a SSL tunnel and expect it to work.

You need something to encapsulate SSH traffic before the tunnel, send it thru, and something else to de-encapsulate the traffic later and send it on its way. Something like [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org) or [Hitch](https://hitch-tls.org).